# How to create views and presenters for abstract models in MVP

Tags: c#, wpf, mvp

We are building our software with Model-View-Presenter passive view strategy. On our software we have a report and different kind of charts. So we have an abstract class for chart for functions that all charts will implement:

```
abstract class AbstractChart
{
    ...
}
```

Then we have concrete classes (models), lets say BarChart and PieChart:

```
class BarChart: AbstractChart
{
    ...
}
class PieChart: AbstractChart
{
    ...
}
```

A report can contain different kind of charts.

```
class Report
{
    public List<AbstractChart> Charts {get; set; }
    ...
}
```

So, we have a problem on drawing different charts on a report:

```
class ReportPresenter
{
    Report _report;
    ReportView _view;
    ...
    FillReportView(Report report)
    {
        foreach(AbstractChart chart in _report.Charts)
        {
            // Here is the problem: How do we create correct
            // view and presenter for abstract chart? We need to
            // create them, so we can add chart view to _view.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using MVVM with WPF?

Comment: We tried MVVM but although it seemed really good, it proved way too complex for our needs.

Comment: My experience is that MVVM *used properly* greatly **reduces** complexity.

Comment: It's already been a good while since we tried out MVVM so I might be wrong but wouldn't we have this same problem (of creating a view-model from abstract model) in MVVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lack of a better idea, I've solved this problem by making a Factory-class that creates an appropriate presenter for a model. For now I have the view created in their presenters, although it would be better to use an IoC-container like Unity.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use WPF `DataTemplates` to tell WPF how to draw each chart type when it encounters an object of that type in the Visual Tree

```
<Application.Resources>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BarChart}">
        <local:BarChartUserControl />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PieChart}">
        <local:PieChartUserControl />
    </DataTemplate>

</Application.Resources>
```

The `DataContext` behind the UserControl will still be your object, so you can build the UserControl with the expectation that the DataContext will be of type `BarChart` or `PieChart`

For example, an `ItemsControl` will draw your list of charts using the correct template for each type with no extra coding:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Charts}" />
```

Or you can manually add your chart object to the visual tree using something like a `ContentControl`

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SomeChartProperty}" />
```

As a side note, I would highly recommend switching to using MVVM instead of MVP. It is perfectly suited to WPF, and is the standard design pattern used when working with WPF or Silverlight.

Comment: That would solve the problem of creating view-objects for the models but who should create the corresponding presenters?

Comment: @teemu I have not worked with MVP when using WPF, however it sounds like it's related to the application code, not the UI code, so I would think it would be created by the ViewModels. I would highly recommend switching to MVVM if you're working with WPF though. I have a [simple MVVM example](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/) on my blog if you're interested.